# Django send email in parts to avoid overhead

Tags: django, multithreading, email

I have a non-profitable website that I need to handle newsletter emails to probably thousand people (lets be realistic and give an upper bound of at most 2000 - 2500 registered users).

I have implemented email this way:

```
@login_required
def SendEmail(request):
   receivers = []
   users = Users.objects.all()
   receivers.append(user.Email for user in users)
   emailTypeSelected = request.POST.get('email_type', -1)

   email_factory = EmailFactory()
   emailManager = email_factory.create_email(emailTypeSelected)
   emailManager.prepare("Some Title")
   emailManager.send_email_to(receivers)

   return render(request, 'new_user_email.html')
```

And here is the "abstract" class.

```
class Email(object):
    title = ""
    plain_message = ""
    html_message = ""

    def send_email_to(self, receivers):
        send_mail(
                    self.title,
                    self.plain_message,
                    SENDER,
                    receivers,
                    html_message=self.html_message
                 )
```

I have tested this code and it takes a while to send 1 email to 1 user. My concern is that for thousand emails will put a big overhead to the server.

I was thinking to do the following:

1. Break the users into group of 100 and send email to those users every 30 minutes.

But I am not sure how this can be implemented. Seems that I will need to implement a sort of threads that will be triggered independently and handle the email for me.

Is there any design pattern that you are aware on how to solve this problem?

Now I know that the best way to do this is to use an external service that handle email newsletter and free up my server from doing this but as a non-profitable website I am trying to minimise the expenses as I already have to pay the server expenses. So at the moment I am trying to find a way to implement that in-house unless big problem arises which will force me to go into third-party services.

Comment: You probably want to use a task queue to do this asynchronously - e.g., [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: Celery sounds good, I didn't knew about this. Thanks @solarissmoke